# Send alert for each row not meeting criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Need help with a stored procedure I'm building that will be run every 10 minutes.

I have two tables

Table: **Transactions**

```
ID    |  TransactionID   |  OrderID
------+------------------+------------
1     |  000125          |  1051
2     |  000132          |  1052
3     | 0000189          |  1053
```

Table: **Orders**

```
OrderID  | TransactionID
---------+---------------------------------
1051     | 00125
1052     | 000313
1053     | 000189
```

As you see the OrderID's that match between two tables have TransactionID's that do match each other.  I am trying to make a job where every 10 minutes a job runs and checks the two tables, if the Transaction ID's do match the associated OrderID's the job needs to send a simple email alert that states in the body of the email:

> Failed to match Transaction ID for Order# and TransactionID#(Orders.Transactions) at "time".

Sometimes there will be several ids that do not match, sometimes there will be many, most of the times all will match.  What is the best way to achieve this?  This is how far I've gotten so far:

```
if exists (select o.OrderID, o.TransactionID
from Orders o
left join Transactions t on t.OrderID = o.OrderID
where o.TransactionID != t.TransactionID and o.OrderID = t.OrderID)
begin

        "send email here for list"
else
begin
        "do not send"

end
```

what is the best way to handle this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is enabled on the server and you have enough permissions to use it, keep it simple and use `sp_send_dbmail`. I'd incorporate this in your agent's job and attach the report of the failed matches as an attachment:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
  @profile_name = 'The name of your DB Mail Profile'
, @recipients = 'recipient@somedomain.com'
, @subject = 'Failed to match Transaction ID for Order# and TransactionID#'
, @body = N'Put your more descriptive email body here...'
, @query = N'select o.OrderID, o.TransactionID
from Orders o
left join Transactions t on t.OrderID = o.OrderID
where o.TransactionID != t.TransactionID and o.OrderID = t.OrderID)'
, @attach_query_result_as_file = 1
, @query_attachment_filename = 'Failed Matches.txt';
```

Comment: is it possible to not attach them but have them in the body?

Comment: Yes you can, but then you cannot use the @query parameter. See Example C from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

You can send the query results in the body by creating the html for the query result like below:

```
DECLARE @xml NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @xml = CAST(( SELECT o.OrderID AS 'td','',o.TransactionID AS 'td'
FROM Orders o
left join Transactions t on t.OrderID = o.OrderID
where o.TransactionID != t.TransactionID and o.OrderID = t.OrderID
FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))

SET @body ='<html><body><H3> Failed Transactions Info </H3>
<table border = 1> 
<tr>
    <th> OrderID </th> <th> TransactionID </th>
</tr>'    

SET @body = @body + @xml +'</table></body></html>'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'SQL TEST MESSAGING', -- replace with your SQL Database Mail Profile 
@body = @body,
@body_format ='HTML',
@recipients = 'test_email@gmail.com', -- replace with your email address
@subject = 'As per your convenience' ;
```